# Django - Pass a file to a session in form_valid

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in `views.py`:

```
class UploadFile(CreateView):
    form_class = UploadFileForm
    template_name = "tool/upload.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tool:edit_columns')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['file'] = self.request.session['file']
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.name = form.instance.file.name
        row_number = form.instance.header_row
        file = form.instance.file
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        names = list(df.columns)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And this code in `forms.py`:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = CheckFile
            fields = ['file', 'header_row', ]
```

I want to pass the `file` object and the columns `names` to the page `edit_columns.html`. I've been looking for infos and I think I have to use a session to pass the `file` object but with the code I tried, I have the following error:
`KeyError: 'file'`

Could you please help me?

Thanks!